# Not playing any video file in python GUI

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

The following code is for opening a `filedialogue`. But it does not play any video file.

It just returns the video file address but in not playing the file.

```
from Tkinter import Tk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename() 

print(filename)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
print(cap)
print(cap.isOpened())

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Adding that it's a college project won't help your cause

Comment: cv2 is a open source library for python

Comment: The code is not indented correctly, it shouldn't even run when the `break` is outside the while loop. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1):

With Tkinter and OpenCV this code is working for me.

if i am using .avi and .mpg format, .mov and .mp4 just print the file path.

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

import cv2

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print(filename)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(250) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Alternatively, 
You can play videos in Python GUI using [PyQt4](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) ( Python bindings for the [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) cross-platform GUI).

Here is the simple example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import phonon


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(960, 540)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        player = phonon.Phonon.VideoPlayer(self)
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        media = phonon.Phonon.MediaSource(filename)
        player.load(media)
        player.play()
        layout.addWidget(player)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you sir,but is there any way to play using opencv and tkinter

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your frame rate. You set it to 0.001 sec, so maybe your video just ended really fast. Try increasing it:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2

Tk().withdraw()
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename() 
print(filename)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(250) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But how can i increase it.also it is showing false value for cap.isOpened().How to make it true

Comment: Well then the problem is your video file doesn't open correctly, maybe it is unsupported format. Anyway, to change frame rate set `cv2.waitkey(250)`.

Comment: sir i have changed the frame rate.But this doesn't help

Comment: actully the while loop is not working.As it is returning false value.

Comment: its the video file captured from webcam